# Razor TextBoxFor Type Number - Show Positive When Below Zero Instead Of Negative

Tags: c#, razor

With the below code statement we create a textbox for a type of number. The box has the up and down arrows and steps by 0.1, when going down below zero the numbers are negative. I'm trying to figure the way to instead of negative numbers when below zero, can I show positive numbers? But also still keep the true value behind as negative?

So as a user I would start at 0 and press the down button to get to -1.2 which is the right value, but I want that to display as a positive so the user would see +1.2 instead of negative while the real value behind remains negative.

Is this possible?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Handicap, true, htmlAttributes: new { placeholder = "Handicap", type = "number", min = "-3.0", step = "0.1", @class = "input-md", Name = "Handicap", ID = "Handicap" })
```

Comment: You could try using a javascript function to intercept and modify the number for display.  There is a Math.abs(number) that you can use.  Something like:  var handicap = @Model.Handicap;  function absHandicap(handicap) {
 var number = Math.abs(handicap);
 return number;
}

Comment: Ok that sounds like a promising idea. I had the theory of JavaScript as well. I'm now only hung up with where I can intercept and inject into the above. In my head I imagine adding a click event or change event that then intercepts the value? Thank you for the response @Brinky